# Getting iframe contents after it gets redirected

Tags: c#, iframe

I have an iframe on my page and it gets redirected automatically.

I need to get the frames contents or the new url after it is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

If there are proper cross site scripting precautions in place it won't be possible.

Pretty much any page with a login nowadays should prevent this.